# How configure launch.json in VSCode to debug an unit ctest(cmake) from the new testing explorer view?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, launch, ctest

I have two cmake unit-test to check url and json helper classes, declared in the CMakeLists.txt of my project like following:

```
########################################
# CMakeLists.txt - Tests               #
########################################
add_executable(urltest test/url.cpp)
add_test(NAME URLTest COMMAND urltest)

add_executable(jsontest test/json.cpp)
add_test(NAME JSONTest COMMAND jsontest )
```

I get visually the test units in the **testing** view of VSCode, and I can run perfectly the both in release mode:
[Execute the unit tests in release mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a90oK.png)

Now if I want debugging it with the other button I have to select a launch configuration, what requires to create manually one launch configuration for each unit test:
[Execute the unit tests in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKNdH.png)

My current launch.json file require so one configuration for each unit test, it's impossible to maintain:

```json
{ // launch.json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CTest-urltest",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/urltest",
            "args": [],
            "initCommands": ["breakpoint set -n main -N entry"],
            "exitCommands": ["breakpoint delete entry"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        {
            "name": "CTest-jsontest",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/jsontest",
            "args": [],
            "initCommands": ["breakpoint set -n main -N entry"],
            "exitCommands": ["breakpoint delete entry"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

I guess the problem is only the `program` attribute, How can we map the program clicked on the **testing** view of VSCode to an unique launch configuration? something like following for example:

```json
{ // launch.json
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "CTest",
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/${command: testing.currentPath}",
            "args": [],
            "initCommands": ["breakpoint set -n main -N entry"],
            "exitCommands": ["breakpoint delete entry"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Weren't all these fancy GUI IDEs and editors, like VSCode, with their pretty dialogs and buttons, supposed to make things easier, to avoid all these yucky `Makefile`s and shell commands? You mean that I must concoct some magic incantation in the form of a convoluted JSON configuration file, to get basic functionality right? That's a darn shame, isn't it? After reading `make`s man page, as lengthy as it is, with plenty of examples, it's always pretty straightofrward for me to simply push `F5` in emacs, and get everything built.

Comment: Yes. By this way the debug part with F5 works as a charm. The issue describing concerns the new [TestExplorer view](https://jpearson.blog/2021/09/01/test-explorer-in-visual-studio-code/) from VSCode: Click on "Debug Test" on an individual unit test asks for a configuration-launch.. yes should be pretty smooth and automatic, maybe an issue :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is now documented in [Debugging Tests](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md#debugging-tests) ([permalink](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/0b46c294b6fa78edd7f8880e068543deea899b75/docs/debug-launch.md#debugging-tests)).

As suggested, prefer `${cmake.testProgram}` over `${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}` as the *program*, since this allows you to have a different launch target while being able to debug the test(s).

Include `"args": [ "${cmake.testArgs}" ]` to be able to run a specific test. Without this, all tests will be debugged even though you only selected one.

#### GDB

```json
{
    "name": "(ctest) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${cmake.testProgram}",
    "args": [ "${cmake.testArgs}" ],
    // other options...
}
```

#### MSVC

```json
{
    "name": "(ctest) Launch",
    "type": "cppvsdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${cmake.testProgram}",
    "args": [ "${cmake.testArgs}" ],
    // other options...
}
```

Comment: Using `${cmake.testProgram}` I get 'program' is missing or empty. Using 
`${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}` it starts debugging but the one I am interested in.

Comment: Really thanks @neris, it works as a charm on my side in using `${cmake.testProgram} ` exactly like you propose (with lldb) =>
<code>{
        "name": "CTest",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${cmake.testProgram}",
        "args": [ "${cmake.testArgs}" ],
        "initCommands": ["breakpoint set -n main -N entry"],
        "exitCommands": ["breakpoint delete entry"],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
</code>

Answer (score 2):

> How can we map the program clicked on the testing view of VSCode to an unique launch configuration?

This seems to be documented in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/debug-launch.md.

In your launch.json, you can have a debug config with this value in `program`

```
// Resolved by CMake Tools:
"program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
```